# Spring BeanPostProcessor not invoked for all beans?

Tags: java, spring

In an imported spring context XML file I define a bean instance that implements `BeanPostProcessor`.

In the importing spring context I define a number of beans (using `BeanDefinitionBuilder` in a custom `BeanDefinitionParser`).

Not all defined beans are given to the `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` method on my `BeanPostProcessor`.

It seems that some other `FactoryBeans` somehow affect this situation. When looking in the `ApplicationContext` instance with a debugger I can see all my beans inside - also the ones not being given to the `BeanPostProcessor`.

How can this happen?

Comment: Maybe your BeanPostProcessor initialized after some of beans ready?

Comment: Maybe it is, but I don't see why. The registration of the BeanPostProcessor is earlier in the XML file (via an <import> element) than the missing beans.

Comment: I just got this error but it seemed like it was in concert with other stuff, maybe AOP driven.